# How to define solver parameters in minizinc for CP-SAT from Google or-tools

Tags: or-tools, minizinc, cp-sat

Using the CP-SAT solver from Google OR-Tools for backend CP-Solver , and want to define the solver parameters in minizinc.
Define the solver config as following :

```
{
    "backend-flags": {
        "interleave_search": true
    },
    "intermediate-solutions": true,
    "parallel": 16,
    "solver": "com.google.or-tools@9.5.2237",
    "time-limit": 120000 }
```

but the error is coming back :

```
ERROR: Unknown command line flag 'interleave_search'
=====ERROR=====
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--params interleave_search:true
```

note that this is the default if you do -f. (1 worker)

Here is the cp-sat msc.in file:

```
{
  "id": "com.google.ortools.sat",
  "name": "OR Tools CP-SAT",
  "description": "Google's Operations Research CP-SAT-LP FlatZinc interface",
  "version": "@PROJECT_VERSION@",
  "mznlib": "../cpsat",
  "executable": "@FZ_REL_INSTALL_BINARY@",
  "tags": ["cpsatlp", "cp", "lcg", "int"],
  "stdFlags": ["-a", "-f", "-p", "-r", "-s", "-v"],
  "extraFlags": [
    ["--params", "Provide parameters interpreted as a text SatParameters proto", "string", ""]
  ],
  "supportsMzn": false,
  "supportsFzn": true,
  "needsSolns2Out": true,
  "needsMznExecutable": false,
  "needsStdlibDir": false,
  "isGUIApplication": false
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help !  is the following define is currect? 
  "extraFlags": [
    ["--params interleave_search", "interleave_search", "bool", "true"]
  ],

Comment: I do not know. I would just add --params, the add the actual parameter string on the command line, like in my .msc file

Comment: thanks a lot !  using " --params interleave_search:true " in command line is worfed